# How to generate Product swagger data in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have managed to generate Swagger data from my site no problem using the docs found [HERE](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/generate-local/)

I go to https://example.com/swagger?store=all  ( obviously with my site instead ) and even authorise it.  The swagger data appears - but there is no catalog-data-product-interface  which is referenced from the REST Api endpoint Docs [HERE](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/) ( Products/ Post ) . The resources allowed in API for my user is ALL - but I can't seem to see the model for products anywhere